# Xamarin/Realm - The type cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method

Tags: c#, generics, xamarin.forms, realm

I've been looking at this for sometime now and know there is something really simple that I'm missing.  The code worked before the previous developer left but now that I need to put out on the iPad, it's not working.  I'm using Visual Studio for Mac.

```
public class DemoPatientService : BaseService, IPatientService
{
    public ObservableCollection<PatientSummary> MockPatientSummary;

    public DemoPatientService()
    {
        MockPatientSummary = realm.All<PatientSummary>().ToObservableCollection();
    }
}

public class PatientSummary : IPatientSummary
{
    public string PatientID { get; set;}
}

public interface IPatientSummary
{
    string PatientID
}

public class BaseService
{
    protected readonly Realm realm;

    public BaseService()
    {
        var config = new RealmConfiguration();
            config = new RealmConfiguration(MYWSettings.Instance.DemoDatabasePath);

        realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
    }
}
```

> Error CS0311: The type 'VSTSQL.Data.Mobile.Models.PatientSummary' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Realm.All()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'PatientSummary' to 'Realms.RealmObject'. (CS0311)

Comment: Has this code really been working before? Looks like the `All<T>()` method requires anything of type `Realms.RealmObject` and `PatienSummary` is clearly not.

Comment: All I know is that some version of the code was deployed to testers so somewhere it worked.

Comment: Then how about you find out about the version history and look up the changes?

Comment: `All<T>` has always had a `where T : RealmObject` generic constraint, so even with older version of Realm, it's impossible that this code has ever worked in its current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object must inherit from RealmObject. Otherwise, it will not be able to be directly stored and accessible from the Realm Database. You can find more information at https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/#models.